# Should I use lateral when querying JSON arrays on postgresql?

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, join

I have this query that works just as expected:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(meta.genres)->>'name' "name", COUNT(id)
FROM movies_metadata meta
GROUP BY "name";
```

But everyone seems to use lateral in queries of this type. If I used a lateral join I could do it like this:

```
SELECT y.x->>'name' "name", COUNT(id)
FROM movies_metadata meta
LATERAL (SELECT jsonb_array_elements(meta.genres) x) y
GROUP BY y.x;
```

Both queries produce the same result so is there any point in using the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of preference.

Many users of Postgres have no problem using set-returning functions in the `select` clause.  And obviously it is acceptable syntax.  These are SQL extensions, so there is no "right" way as specified by the standard.

That said, I have a strong preference for putting set-returning functions in the `from` clause and using a lateral join.  I want the `from` clause to answer the question:  "what is the space of rows that are going into this query?".  I want the "select" clause to answer:  "what columns and expressions are being returned".

In addition, other databases tend to require that set-returning functions be in the `from` clause.

So, I find a lateral join to be more in the spirit of SQL.  But both methods are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Both queries are equivalent for this use case. The second form, that uses a lateral join, is much more flexible that the first. Say you wanted to read more  keys from the nested elements: you can't do that with the first form, you need to use the second.

```
select
    m.id,
    y.x ->> 'name' as name,
    y.x ->> 'key2' as key2,
    y.x ->> 'key3' as key3
from movies_metadata m
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(m.genres) as y(x)
```

Note that you don't need a nested `select`: as shown above, `jsonb_array_elements()` is a set-returning function, that can be placed directly in a `from` clause.